# Broadcast receiver not working after onResume

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I have registered a `broadcast receiver` in onResume of the `fragment`, But it is not fired at all, `onResume()` method is called but `broadcast receiver` is not working after registering in `onResume()`. Same is the case with the `activity` I have used this code in some `activity` but the `broadcast receiver` is never called. It fires for the first time because I have also registered broadcast receiver in onCreate, but onResume it is not called, even though I have registered it again in onResume

```
@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(tagAddedToSearch);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(tagRemovedFromSearch);

    }


 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        Log.e(" on resume","onresume tag serach");
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(tagRemovedFromSearch,
                new IntentFilter("removeFeedTag"));
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(tagAddedToSearch,
                new IntentFilter("addFeedTag"));
        ////check app update of app
//        CheckAppUpdate.with(getContext()).onUpdateNeeded(getContext()).check();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should **send** broadcast after Create a broadcast receiver using below method:

[sendBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent))

Without sending it, the broadcast could not be triggered.

Comment: I am sending a broadcast but it is not fired at all

Comment: It is fired for the first time, but when i go toa nother activity and come back not fired at all